# How do I get the date a Mamba environment was created?

Tags: conda, virtualenv, python-venv, mamba

I'd like to see the date I made a mamba environment on my linux machine. I can't find anything in the docs for this. I tried the following command, but it didn't give me the info I wanted.
`mamba env export --from-history -n moose_peacock`

Any suggestions (other than detective work with package version release dates)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Conda Metadata

Conda environments<sup>**1**</sup> keep metadata in the `${CONDA_PREFIX}/conda-meta` folder and specifically the first line of the `${CONDA_PREFIX}/conda-meta/history` file records the date of the first transaction (creation).

### Example: Single Environment

Let's create an environment and then check the first few lines of the `history` file:

**Interactive (Activating) Environment**

```bash
$ mamba create -n foo
$ mamba activate foo
(foo) $ head -n3 ${CONDA_PREFIX}/conda-meta/history
==> 2023-11-06 23:59:57 <==
# cmd: /Users/user/miniconda3/bin/mamba create -n foo
# conda version: 23.7.4
```

**Single-Line Command with Conda Run**

```bash
$ mamba run -n foo bash -c "head -n3 \${CONDA_PREFIX}/conda-meta/history"
==> 2023-11-06 23:59:57 <==
# cmd: /Users/user/miniconda3/bin/mamba create -n foo
# conda version: 23.7.4
```

### Script for All Environments

The following bash script will list this information for all non-**base** environments:

**show-env-creation-all.sh**

```bash
#!/bin/bash -l                                                                                                                        

_CONDA_PREFIX=$(conda run -n base bash -c "echo \${CONDA_PREFIX}")

for env in ${_CONDA_PREFIX}/envs/*; do
    if [ -d "$env" ]; then
        echo "Environment: $(basename $env)"
        head -n3 "$env/conda-meta/history"
        echo " "
    fi
done
```

which can be run with:

```bash
bash -l show-env-creation-all.sh
```

---

<sub>**[1]**: The term *"Mamba environment"* is a misnomer. *Mamba* is an interface for *Conda* environments - it's all still Conda.</sub>